# create a shape file

Tags: python, ogr

I want to create a shapefile (a line) using 2 points.

i have the following script:

```
import ogr, sys, os

line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint(10,10)
line.AddPoint(20,20)

driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds=driver.CreateDataSource('C:\test.shp')
layer=ds.CreateLayer('test', geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString)
fieldDefn=ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger)
layer.CreateField(fildDefn)
featureDefn=layer.GetLayerDefn()
feature=ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
feature.SetGeometry(line)
feature.SetField('id',1)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

I have two errors..

"ERROR 1: Failed to create file. shp file.
ERROR 4: Failed to open Shapefile"

Anyone have an idea of what the problem is?
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: if you wonder why your id field won't work:
there's a typo where you create the field :`layer.CreateField(fildDefn)` should be `layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to inform the geodetic system. This way below works.

```
import ogr, sys, os
import osgeo.osr as osr

line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint(10,10)
line.AddPoint(20,20)

driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds=driver.CreateDataSource('test.shp')

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

layer=ds.CreateLayer('test', srs, ogr.wkbLineString)
fieldDefn_=ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn_)
featureDefn=layer.GetLayerDefn()
feature=ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
feature.SetGeometry(line)
feature.SetField('id',1)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `\t` characters; they signify a tab character in a python string literal. Either double the slash, or use a raw python string instead:

```
ds=driver.CreateDataSource('C:\\test.shp')
```

or

```
ds=driver.CreateDataSource(r'C:\test.shp')
```

(note the `r` at the start of the string).